# Show dialog to choose workspace while it starts

Tags: eclipse, workspace

I know its a silly question but i am stuck into it from 2 hours..Can any body tell me how should i enable the dialog which opens at the time we  start eclipse and we choose workspace location from there.

See I want this window to be displayed first when eclipse starts

[image]

By mistake I have checked "Use this as the default and do not ask again".

Please guide me how to show up this dialog again

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can find it here :

```
Menu: Window -> Preferences -> General -> Startup and Shutdown -> Workspaces -> Prompt for workspace on startup
```

Eclipse preferences has a lot of options. **You can search for specific options by typing in the filter text box at the top of the preferences dialog.**

If you type in 'startup' for instance the list will be much shorter.

Answer (score 6):

window > preferences > general > startup and shutdown > workspaces

then check 'Prompt for workspace on startup'

Answer (score 2):

If your workspace is corrupted and Eclipse doesn't startup with your currently pre-selected workspace, you may edit `SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG=false` to `SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG=true`
which is located in file

```
C:\PathToEclipse\eclipse\configuration\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs
```

before you start the IDE.