# Can Eclipse for Java and Eclipse for WEBMethods be on the same hard drive?

Tags: java, webmethods

I am new to WEBMethods. I have been working on a Java service for a project. I really need to be able to write some code in regular Java for some quick testing of reading in a simple text expression with some regular expressions. Nothing at all that fancy with the Java part. But eclipse currently is set up for WEBMethods and I need to be in a regular Java mode for Eclipse (If there is such a thing). At home I have the standard eclipse version and have no trouble writting code. But at work I have WEBMethods installed in the Eclipse (Software AG Designer). I think that if I can write the code in regular Java then I can just copy and paste it into the WEBMethods Java services and set up the INPUT and OUTPUT variables and it should work. But currently I cannot find a way to just write Java code like I do from my home computer.

Question: How can I write just a regular Java program (classes, packages, ...etc...) with a machine with WEBMethods installed? Do I have to install another session of Eclipse on my hard drive? (I tried this a while back and there was an issue with having more than one session of Eclipse on the machine).

Java Web Services Code:

```
package DssAccessBackup.services.flow;

import com.wm.data.*;
import com.wm.util.Values;
import com.wm.app.b2b.server.Service;
import com.wm.app.b2b.server.ServiceException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public final class new_javaService_SVC

{

    /** 
     * The primary method for the Java service
     *
     * @param pipeline
     *            The IData pipeline
     * @throws ServiceException
     */
    public static final void new_javaService(IData pipeline)
            throws ServiceException {
        // pipeline
        IDataCursor pipelineCursor = pipeline.getCursor();
            String  inputFileName = IDataUtil.getString( pipelineCursor, "inputFileName" );
        pipelineCursor.destroy();

        // pipeline
        IDataCursor pipelineCursor_1 = pipeline.getCursor();
        IDataUtil.put( pipelineCursor_1, "fileName", "fileName" );

        // outDoc
        IData   outDoc = IDataFactory.create();
        IDataUtil.put( pipelineCursor_1, "outDoc", outDoc );
        pipelineCursor_1.destroy();

        String fileName = new String();
        fileName = null;

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\itpr13266\\Desktop\\TestFile.txt"));
            String line = null;
            //Will read through the file until EOF
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Try-Catch Message - " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    // --- <<IS-BEGIN-SHARED-SOURCE-AREA>> ---



    // --- <<IS-END-SHARED-SOURCE-AREA>> ---
}
```

Comment: I'm typically not installing Eclipse, just download zip, unzip it and run it. Only problem is, that Eclipse can allocate a lot of memory, so it is not recommended to do such things with 4GB of RAM...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to install another Eclipse for Java development. WebMethods Designer (v9) comes with Java tooling. Just open the Java perspective and use it.

[image: Adding Java perspective]

Besides that you should use the Service Development perspective, when developing WebMethods Java Services, because WM Designer handles Java services in a special way, which could make importing standard Java files difficult.

Comment: Thank you. I found the tab and Java is there.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem running multiple instances of Eclipse at the same time as long as they point to different workspaces.

Normally you get a dialog to choose the workspace when Eclipse starts up. If not, check this answer on how to enable that dialog: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8616216/1599890

So if you download, unzip and set up Eclipse for Java development and point it to another workspace than Software AG Designer uses you should be good to go.